# sql replace cell value with column name and avoid null values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hi i have two tables Agents, Skills and target query as below

Agents

```
-------------------------------------
PF       |Name       |HireDate       |
---------|-----------|---------------|
54       |Jack       |01-Jan-2012    |
55       |Aline      |01-Jan-2012    |
-------------------------------------
```

Skills

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
PF       |Writing    |Swimming       |KickOff    |Shopping   |
---------|-----------|---------------|-----------------------
54       |Null       |01-Dec-2012    |Null       |Null       |
55       |01-Mar-2012|01-FeB-2012    |Null       |15-Nov-2012|
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want query to select PF, Hiredate from Agents table and avaliable skills from skills table, The date on skills tables means that agents learned this skill on this data, but if there is null value that means agents didn't have this skill, but i want to replace date with column name The below table explane what is my query

MyQuery

```
------------------------------------------------------
PF       |HireDate       |Avalivble skills            |
---------|---------------|----------------------------|
54       |01-Jan-2012    |Swimming                    |
55       |01-Jan-2012    |Writing, Swimming, Shopping |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  PF
,       HireDate
,       replace(
            iif(Writing is null;'';'Writing, ') +
            iif(Swimming is null;'';'Swimming, ') +
            iif(KickOff is null;'';'KickOff, ') +
            iif(Shopping is null;'';'Shopping, ') + '$';
            ', $'; '')
from    Agents a
join    Skills s
on      s.PF = a.PF
```

Comment: Thanks but its return error "Syntax error (missing operator)"

Comment: You'll need to trim off the trailing ', '

Comment: @openshac: I guess you could... not always important though.

Comment: Depending on your locale, try to relace the `;` with `,` ?

Comment: Tested in Euro locale MS Access: `select  a.PF
,       HireDate
,       replace(
            iif(Writing is null,'','Writing, ') +
            iif(Swimming is null,'','Swimming, ') +
            iif(KickOff is null,'','KickOff, ') +
            iif(Shopping is null,'','Shopping, ') + '$',
            ', $', '')
from    Agents a
inner join    Skills s
on      s.PF = a.PF`